# ggplot ribbon with constant `ymin` and `ymax`

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following simple line graph with ribbons denoting thresholds of interest along the y-axis.

```
library(ggplot2)
main.df <- data.frame(time = c(1:20, 1:20), 
                level = runif(40), 
                type = c(rep('A', 20), rep('B', 20)))

gg <- ggplot(main.df, aes(x = time, y = level, colour = type)) 
gg + geom_ribbon(ymin = 0.1, ymax = 0.25, fill = 'green') + 
    geom_ribbon(ymin = 0.25, ymax = 0.5, fill = 'yellow') + 
    geom_ribbon(ymin = 0.5, ymax = 0.95, fill = 'red') + 
    geom_line()
```

[image: Desired ggplot but not desired method]

I have made many attempts to set the `data` property of `geom_ribbon` to give me more flexibility and clean up my code. Here is one such example.

```
rib.df <- data.frame(low = c(0.1, 0.25, 0.5), high = c(0.25, 0.50, 0.95), 
                     lab = c('green', 'yellow', 'red'))

gg + geom_ribbon(data = rib.df,   
      aes(ymin = low, ymax = high, fill = lab), 
      inherit.aes=FALSE) + geom_line()
```

This particular one has the error that the aesthetic x is missing. Which interestingly was not a problem in the prior example. I have tried setting the x and y in it seems every combination of inside the `aes` and not. I am also unclear as to why sometimes the `geom_ribbon` wants a `y` when it is not a required aesthetic.

My question in summary: how to call `geom_ribbon` setting the `data` argument to achieve a result similar to the above manual calls?

I will also be glad to learn about efficient ways to achieve a similar visual result using other `geom`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
rib2 = rbind(rib.df, rib.df)
rib2$x = rep(c(-Inf, Inf), each = nrow(rib.df))

gg + geom_ribbon(data = rib2,   
      aes(x = x, ymin = low, ymax = high, fill = lab),
      inherit.aes=FALSE) + 
   geom_line()
```

Ribbons are made to have ymin and ymax values *that change* for various x values. In this case where you're just drawing rectangles, you could simplify by using `geom_rect`, in which case you could set `xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf` outside of `aes()` and use the `rib.df` from your question. This way you don't have to double the data to show the ymin and ymax are the same at the min and max x values.

```
gg + geom_rect(data = rib.df,   
          aes(ymin = low, ymax = high, fill = lab),
          xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf,
          inherit.aes=FALSE) +
    geom_line()
```